# Grafana showing all filters in legend

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm using InfuxDB as a datasource and have 2 filters, `currency` and `host`.
When viewing my data in Grafana for a specific field, the legend contains the 2 filters:

[image]

`total` is the field and `currency` and `host` are the filters.

Is there a way to format the legend in order to change this to either remove it or change it to `Total USD`?

My query if it helps:

```
from(bucket: "Test")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "orders")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "total")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["host"] == "EU")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["currency"] == "${currency}")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```